# AngularFire $onAuth() not firing after initial redirect back from GitHub, but fires on page refresh; works fine with popup

Tags: angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm having issues getting AngularFire's $onAuth() to fire after a successful redirect authentication to/from GitHub. If I use `auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect('github')` it will redirect to GitHub and back again after successful authentication, but when it gets back to my Angular app, the `auth.$onAuth()` callback doesn't get called. if I then refresh the page, it does get called with the expected authinfo. If I sign out (`$unauth()`) and sign back in again, the `$onAuth()` callback again doesn't get called until I refresh the page.

At first I figured this was something I was doing wrong, but I noticed that if I change the code to use `$authWithOAuthPopup()` instead, the app works as expected: the `$onAuth()` callback is called as soon as the popup closes, passing the authdata.

Note sure if this is a bug in AngularFire of if I'm just misunderstanding how to use it. I've searched for examples and I think I'm using it correctly, but if the problem is in my code, please let me know how I should be doing this.

I've put a minimal repo case into a GitHub repo: https://github.com/drstearns/angularfire-oath-redir. The code currently uses `$authWithOAuthRedirect`, and you'll notice that nothing is logged to the console when you return from GitHub the first time you authenticate, nor after you sign out and sign back in. If you refresh the page after signing in, it works fine. If you change it to use `$authWithOAuthPopup()`, it also works fine.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
angular.module('ChatApp', ['firebase'])
    .constant('firebaseUrl', 'https://info343chat.firebaseio.com')
    .controller('ChatController', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth, firebaseUrl) {
        //create reference to the Firebase
        var rootRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);

        //create an authentication service for this firebase
        var auth = $firebaseAuth(rootRef);

        //when the user clicks the signin button...
        $scope.signin = function() {
            //authenticate with github using a popup window
            //BUG? change this to $authWithOAuthPopup and
            //it works correctly
            auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect('github')
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        };

        //when the user clicks the signout button...
        $scope.signout = function() {
            //un-authenticate (sign out)
            auth.$unauth();
        };

        //when the authentication state changes...
        auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
            //for debugging
            //not firing after initial redirect back from GitHub
            console.log('$onAuth');
            console.log(authData);

            //if we have authentication data
            if (authData) {
                //...
            }
            else {
                //...
            }
        }); //$onAuth()

        //...other controller code
    }); //ChatController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report!  It is indeed a bug, though it's actually in firebase.js itself.  And fortunately it was fixed recently.  If you update your firebase.js reference from 2.2.4 to 2.3.1, the problem should be resolved.